# Get tablespace name from dump file

Tags: oracle, tablespaces, impdp

I have an Oracle dump file which I need to import but do not know what is its tablespace name. How can I get it from the dump file? I know that it is possible to get many information using impdp MASTER_ONLY flag but can't see there any information about dump's tablespace.

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_import.htm

```
impdp hr/hr DIRECTORY=dpump_dir1 DUMPFILE=expfull.dmp
SQLFILE=dpump_dir2:expfull.sql
```